# bootstrap v3 with jquery no conflict

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, mootools, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently using mootool on my website. Now thinking to use bootstrap for look and feel.

I have situation i must have to use mootool, but in order to use bootstrap i need to use jquery.

Is anyone know how to handle this situation.

Like can i use bootstrap with jquery using jquery no conflict. if i do so will bootstrap detect jquery's no conflict.

Note: - there is mootool bootstrap version available by another provider but i dont want to use that.(i want to use standard version of bootstrap with jquery)

Please share any idea.

Regards,
Raj

Comment: You should use Aaron's, https://github.com/anutron/mootools-bootstrap - what is the reason to not use that one?

Comment: Hi Sergio... Thank you for reply.. basically i have mootool core and i tried using your suggested plugin but it is not working...may be i am missing something here... could you please help me with steps..

Comment: Can you post the error you got from the console here also? btw, was it you posting in the moo-users Google group?